# Angular reserve query parameters from url when swith state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, url-parameters, query-string

I'm using query parameters to save some data when user in not login/register into my app.

When the user is trying to perform some action while not logged in I'm not let him do it and navigate him to the login/sign up page, and using query parameters I can save the action
he was trying to do, and when he will login I'm letting him do it.
But the problem starts when the user swith between login/sign up
because the url not saving query parameters.

the swith is done like this:

```
    <a href="/#!/signup">Sign up</a>
    ....
    <a href="/#!/signin">Sign in</a>
```

My question is how can keep this data on the url when click on the signin/signup links?

Comment: The "location is not defined" error and the url not having query parameters are a different problem. You should fix the former first. Did you inject the `$location` service in your controller?

Comment: yes, I fixed the former error by adding $location service into my controller.